# php oop connection failing

Tags: php, oop

```
          <!----  Database File  --->


      <?php

      defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
      defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "faizy");
      defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "faizy");
      defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");

      class MySQLDatabase {

          private $connection;

          function __construct() {
              $this->open_connection();
          }

          public function open_connection() {
              $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
              if(!$this->connection) {
                  die("Database connection Failed: " .mysqli_error($this->connection));
              }else {
                  $db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME);
                  if(!$db_select) {
                     die("Database connection Failed: " .mysqli_error($this->connection)); 
                  }
              }
          }

          public function close_connection() {
              if(isset($this->connection)) {
                  mysqli_close($this->connection);
                  unset($this->connection);
              }
          }

          public function query($sql) {
              $result = mysqli_query($sql, $this->connection);
              $this->confirm_query($result);
              return $result;

          }


          private function confirm_query($result) {
              if(!$result) {
                   die("Database connection Failed: " .mysqli_error($this->connection)); 
              }
          }


      }

      $database = new MySQLDatabase();
      $database->close_connection();

      ?>

      <!----Config FIle which ---->

      <?php
          defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
          defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "faizy");
          defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "faizy");
          defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");
      ?>

      <!--index.html-->
      <body>
       <?php
       require_once '../includes/database.php';
       if(isset($database)){ echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; }
       echo "<br/>";
       echo $database->mysql_prep("It's Working <br />");

       $sql  = "INSERT INTO users (id, username,password,first_name,last_name) VALUES(1,'walifaizy','12345','wali','faizy')";
       $result = $database->query($sql);
       ?>
       </body>



        [![Below are the errors][1]][1]
```

> When i insert something in database than these warning and notice are coming,can anyone suggest me how to solve these errors,I am got stuck because of these warnings and notice,I am defining the constants in proper way and everything is correct than why these notice are coming
>   [image]

Comment: One issue is you have the args the wrong way round in your `mysqli_query`. The other is that you close the connection (and unset) it after opening the connection, and before you try and use it to query.

Answer (score 0):

Check the line 38 ...mysqli_query($con,"your query").This is the correct syntax.rewrite your code in this format

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$sql)

Comment: Try to rewrite php in simple manner.Avoid using class..Check wheather it works

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the database include file you close the database right after you opened it:

```
$database = new MySQLDatabase();
$database->close_connection();
```

hence it doesn't have a connection.

Comment: Thanks,its work now but when should i have to close the connection

Comment: It will close itself, but if that is not satisfying to you, try doing it in a `__destruct()` which is the opposite of `__construct()`.